# run Masterpage error HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

why can i have this error. i take some solution from microsoft to enable diretory browing and default document but cant get this solution. some one help.sorry my english is bad.

i have this error

> *HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory. Most likely causes: A default
>   document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory
>   browsing is not enabled on the server. Things you can try: If you do
>   not want to enable directory browsing, ensure that a default document
>   is configured and that the file exists. Enable directory browsing. Go
>   to the IIS Express install directory. Run appcmd set config
>   /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable
>   directory browsing at the server level. Run appcmd set config
>   ["SITE_NAME"] /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true
>   to enable directory browsing at the site level. Verify that the
>   configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is
>   set to true in the site or application configuration file. Detailed
>   Error Information: Module    DirectoryListingModule Notification
>
>   ExecuteRequestHandler Handler    StaticFile Error Code       0x00000000
>   Requested URL    http://localhost:37365/ Physical Path
>
>   c:\users\hendrick\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\mylibrary.com\mylibrary.com Logon Method       Anonymous
>   Logon User       Anonymous Request Tracing Directory
>
>   C:\Users\Hendrick\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\MYLIBRARY.COM
>   More Information: This error occurs when a document is not specified
>   in the URL, no default document is specified for the Web site or
>   application, and directory listing is not enabled for the Web site or
>   application. This setting may be disabled on purpose to secure the
>   contents of the server. View more information »*

Comment: Did you try what the error message is saying to enable directory browsing?

Comment: U should have a content page that includes this master page. Not sure why u load the master page

Comment: sorry, i didnt notice run wrong page =='